# Is there a way to configure PHP so that echo 0==1; outputs 0 or false?

Tags: php

Is there a way to configure PHP through `.ini` files so that `echo 0==1;` outputs `0` or `false`?

Comment: If you're looking for easier debugging use `var_dump($foo)` instead of `echo $foo`.

Comment: your question is unclear. Configure how, through `.ini` files?

Comment: @Fred, yes, I was thinking of php.ini

Comment: @mario Good question. I haven't found anything on php.net yet. I doubt it though.

Comment: I'll just be honest that even if you were to propose something like this to the PHP internals group it would probably die a fiery death. A switch that changes one of the fundamental premises of PHP would be a dangerous thing.

Comment: @mario well Mario, going through php.net/Google, it doesn't look like you can so I guess you're left with using it in your files. If you want to use this on a global level, then you could use an `include/require` with a single ternary directive, that's the best I can offer as a solution as a global method.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I agree and believe that modifying that behaviour would require modifying/recompiling the interpreter so that when it auto-typecasts boolean `false` to a string, it would produce `"0"` instead of `""`, but that might just open Pandora's box.

Comment: @Shomz Pandora herself would've *freaked* hehe

Comment: @mario *Addendum* to my above comment. You could do/try what I suggested along with sessions, since those can be carried over multiple files. ;-)

Comment: Do I deserve a donwvote? I like my question, simple and neat, I would dare to say cool :-(  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can typecast the expression to integer:

```
echo (int)(1==0);
```

There's a segment called `Converting to boolean` here, but it's still not fully explained: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

It is actually autocasting `false` to an empty string (`""`) (by design, see the link above), and `echo` then outputs it as such because `echo` only accepts strings:

```
echo (int)false;    // 0
echo (int)true;     // 1
echo (string)false; // nothing
echo (string)true;  // 1
```

Comment: yes, my underlying question seems to be whether there is a reason.

Comment: Seems like it's by design. It probably converts the boolean false to empty string.

Comment: Who knows... probably didn't expect people to echo booleans (which technically become strings after autocasting).

Comment: I am not sure it makes sense: if `echo (string)true; -> 1`, then why not  `echo (string)false; -> 0` ? I note that even `echo (bool)false; -> ""`. I do not see any drawback to have 0  instead of the empty string. Anyway, I am now thinking your answer by typecast is what whoever designed PHP would reply too.

Comment: I completely agree and we cannot do much more than guess the logic behind their reasoning. Besides, I can guarantee this is not the only flaw you'll find in PHP. :)

Answer (score 6):

Use a ternary operator ([PHP Ternary Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)):

```
echo (0==1) ? 'false' : 'true';
```

Comment: Not sure this is really what OP meant by "configure". Btw. using a ternary over a regular conditional is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: it does not answer what I am asking. Since `echo 1==1;` outputs `1`, I would like that  `echo 1==0;` outputs `0` (without using ..?.. : ..,  var_dump, or similar tricks). Why not?

Comment: Not my downvote here Garry, but @Shomz did give a constructive comment.